# multidimensional python list element assignment error

Tags: python, oop, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am defining a class game with dimensions n,m. The init method creates creates two boards, one for each player

```
class game:

def __init__(self, n, m):
    rows = [0 for _ in range m]
    self.board1 = [rows for _ in range n]
    self.board2 = [rows for _ in range n]
```

when i assign an value to board1[0][0] it also assigns the same value to board1[1][0], board1[2][0], ...board1[n][0] as well as board2[0-n][0]

for example,

```
game(3,4)
game.board1[0][0] = 1
print("board 1: {}\nboard 2: {}).format(self.board1, self.board2))
```

returns

```
board 1: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
board 2: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: The inner dimension are just links to `rows` which is not copied but referenced in each iteration.  They change because all of the list items reference the same backing object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some working code first:

```
class game:

def __init__(self, n, m):
    self.board1 = [ [0]*m for _ in range(n) ]
    self.board2 = [ [0]*m for _ in range(n) ]

new_game = game(3,4)
new_game.board1[0][1] = 1
print("board 1: {}\nboard 2: {}".format(new_game.board1, new_game.board2))
```

Why does this work and not what you wrote? Because, when you create `rows = [0 for _ in range m]` and then pass it to the different boards, it just passes the same object multiple times to both the boards. So, instead of your boards being

```
[rows1, rows2, rows3]
```

They are

```
[rows, rows, rows]
```

And since it is referencing the same object, when you modify one of them, you get the same value reflected across.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was probably why but I didn't know how to generate the board otherwise. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is saying that `self.board[n] = rows` which is an object.  To save memory python doesn't copy objects that it can just reference.  You can use the `id(obj)` command to see that they all reference the exact same object.

```
In [34]: id(game.board1[0])
Out[34]: 4439424520

In [35]: id(game.board1[1])
Out[35]: 4439424520

In [36]: id(game.board2[1])
Out[36]: 4439424520
```

Comment: Ahh ok, i thought this was it but didnt kniw i could use id() to confirm it. Thank you! I decided to turn a kata I did on CodeWars into a class to practice oop. This is good to learn